# I want to repeat text according to user input

Tags: bash

There is a question I'm struggling with.  I have a file named `filex.txt`

```
$ cat filex.txt
I love my India.
```

I want it to print multiple times by getting users' input. An example is shown below, where I'm trying to repeat the text 30 time silently put it in a separate text file.

```
echo "Number of times you want to repeat:"
read repeat # for example user entered 30
cat link_no_follow.txt | perl -ne 'for$i(0..$repeat){print}' >filex2.txt
```

I used a variable `$repeat` to store the user input. But it doesn't work. Can someone provide me a solution, please?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use `perl` for looping, you could use bash directory.  Consider the following example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

content="$(cat filex.txt)"

echo -n "Number of times you want to repeat: "
read repeat

for ((i = 0; i < repeat; ++i)); do
    echo "${content}"
done
```

The script starts off by reading the content of `filex.txt` into a variable named `content`.  Then it prompts for the number of times to repeat and reads that from the user into the variable `repeat`.

Next, it uses a `for` loop to print `content` `repeat` number of times.  The `for` loop's structure is:

```
for ((init; condition; update))
```

The `init` portion is performed one time when the loop starts,  Next the `condition` portion is evaluated.  If it's true, then the loop executes.  Once that pass through the loop is complete, it performs the `update` portion.  Next is re-evaluates the condition.  That continues until the condition is false.  `++i` is short-hand for `i = i + 1`.

Running that script, I get:

```
$ ./ex.sh
Number of times you want to repeat: 3
I love my India.
I love my India.
I love my India.
```

Comment: Okay sir got, I'm new here. Sorry for that. Let me edit it for you.

Comment: amm ! It's solved thanks. You gave useful script. I'll use it in my next project. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your shell variable `repeat` is invisible inside the single-quoted perl expression.

If you really want to use perl for this, you could do something like

```
$ repeat=3
$ 
$ perl -ne 'BEGIN{$repeat = shift} print $_ x $repeat' "$repeat" filex.txt 
I love my India.
I love my India.
I love my India.
```

which uses the perl argument vector (implicitly, via `shift`) to pass the value of shell variable `repeat` and assign it to perl variable `$repeat`.
Note that if `filex.txt` contains multiple lines, then this will repeat each line `$repeat` times in turn.

Comment: I added >repeated.txt
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$repeat = shift} print $_ x $repeat' "$repeat" filex.txt >repeated.txt
It worked man thanks... I got the output finally... Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to prompt for and read your `repeat` variable so assuming it has the value 5:

```
$ seq "$repeat" | xargs -I{} cat filex.txt
I love my India.
I love my India.
I love my India.
I love my India.
I love my India.
```